# Can flash player 11 encode microphone raw audio data to AAC or mp3?

Tags: flash, rtsp, vlc, wowza

We need send h264 from flash to Wowza and after to vlc by RTSP protocol. But if we send sound in Speex codec, we not listens sound. what it is possible to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Transcoder AddOn for Wowza to convert the Speex audio on the fly to AAC or MP3.
http://www.wowza.com/addons/wowza-transcoder-addon

Here's how we configured our video recording product to leave the H.264 video data intact and transcode the sound from Speex to AAC so that a proper MP4 file that can be played on iOS/Android is obtained:
http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp4-filesh-264-and-aac-with-hdfvr-and-wowza/

Comment: I know that, but this method has a disadvantage, increases the delay. We fixed bug in source code vlc, and now vlc can receive audio in speex codec.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Encode audio from microphone into AAC/HE-AAC format you can't do it from Flash Player right now but i am not pretty sure about mp3 encoding from FP.

Comment: FP can encode raw sound to mp3 by using 3rd party mp3 conversion libraries. [Audior](http://audior.ec) is one example.